# Im running a react app using npm start but i get an "ENOENT" error saying my Path is wrong, what could it be?

Tags: reactjs, enoent

Im working with react. I finished my application , but when i want to run it , it gives me an ENOENT error.

[image]

Comment: You've cut off the right side of the error.

Comment: Also, the behaviour of start depends on how it's defined in package.json

Comment: I know, but i don't know why is happening, everything ran perfectly with the same scripts

Comment: do npm install then npm start, also if you are correct directory of your project that contains package.json with 'start' script

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running `npm start` from your home directory, which is likely not correct. Enter the project directory with `cd` first.